# If I have a .NET website, do search engines see my webpage content as aspx pages or as html pages?

Tags: html, asp.net

**If I have an  ASP.NET website, do search engines see my webpage content as aspx pages or as html pages?**

I know that if I view an aspx page in a web browser, the ASP.NET server processes the aspx page and sends it to my browser as an html file.

If a search engine looks at the same page, does it also see the same html page that I see in my browser, or does it see the aspx page underneath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search engine will see the same content that a browser would. The aspx page will run through the IIS server to render the content and output html, javascript, etc.  This is the same content a web browser would receive.

Answer (score 0):

For ASP.Net application it doesn't matter if user accessed it from browser, or it was search engine bot. Result HTML will be the same, so it doesn't matter.

ASP.Net itself **NEVER** sends your aspx\ascx file content outside of web server. It always compile it and renders as HTML.

It would only matter if you handle it manually in application itself and will return aspx content if request come from search engine bot, but as for me it hasn't any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Search engines, like browsers, don't care what the extension of the file is.  They only care what the URI is (for example, http, https, etc..).  Then, they read the content of the data returned, and that content contains a header called a content type, which indicates the type of file it is.

Web browsers and search engines only see html for ASPX pages (well, javascript, css, etc.. as well).  ASPX pages render their pages as HTML.